# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when iterating through an array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

```
public static int calcScore(char[] inputChars) {
    int gameScore = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < inputChars.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(inputChars[i]);
        if(inputChars[i] == 'X') {
            gameScore += 10;
            gameScore += getPointsStrikeSpare(i, inputChars);
        } else if (inputChars[i] == '-') {
            gameScore += 0;
        } else if (inputChars[i] == '/') {
            gameScore += 10;
            gameScore += getPointsStrikeSpare(i, inputChars);
        } else {
            gameScore += Character.getNumericValue(inputChars[i]);
        }
    }
    return gameScore;
}
```

So my problem is that I want to itterate through the *inputChars* array (created using *.toCharArray()*) and it works fine but it cannot process the last character.

Here is the content of the **input** variable: "X-/X5-8/9-X811-4/X".

**inputChars** is input.toCharArray().

Here is the output when I run the code :

```
X
-
/
X
5
-
8
/
9
-
X
8
1
1
-
4
/
X
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 18
    at betterCalculateScore.getPointsStrikeSpare(betterCalculateScore.java:37)
    at betterCalculateScore.calcScore(betterCalculateScore.java:20)
    at betterCalculateScore.main(betterCalculateScore.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

I have tried using **i < inputChars.length - 1** but then it just doesn't count the last character.

Here is the content of **getPointsStrikeSpare** :

```
    public static int getPointsStrikeSpare(int i, char[] inputChars) {
    int points = 0;

    if(inputChars[i] == 'X') {
        if(inputChars[i+1] == '-') {
            points += 0;
        } else if (inputChars[i+1]== '/') {
            points += 10;
        } else {
            points += Character.getNumericValue(inputChars[i+1]);
        }
        if(inputChars[i+2] == '-') {
            points += 0;
        } else if (inputChars[i+2]== '/') {
            points += 10;
        } else {
            points += Character.getNumericValue(inputChars[i+2]);
        }
    } else {
        if(inputChars[i+1] == '-') {
            points += 0;
        } else if (inputChars[i+1]== '/') {
            points += 10;
        } else {
            points += Character.getNumericValue(inputChars[i+1]);
        }
    }
    return points;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the content of the method 'getPointsStrikeSpare' here.

Comment: Hi, I added it to the bottom of the post :)

Comment: Any of these could fail as you get toward the end of the string ... else if (inputChars[i+1]== '/') ... do a test to verify i+N <= length of string

Comment: all i+1 and i+2 will throw above exception for i as last element.

Comment: The last character is an `X`, what do you expect the next character and the character after that to be?

Comment: You might want to divide up the tasks and code each task separately.  Get the marks into the appropriate frames first.  Next, convert the marks into rolls.  Next, calculate the score.  Finally, display the score.  The 10th frame requires a different parsing of the input string than the first 9 frames.

Comment: What do you mean by convert the marks into rolls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if  the value of 'i' is equal to or less than the length of (array_size - 1), a[i] would be valid.

However, in this method,     `public static int getPointsStrikeSpare(int i, char[] inputChars)` one can see that a[i+1] and a[i+2] end up getting queried in different code paths in the if-else structure. So, if your 'i' index already reached the end of the array, this is going to be Out of Bounds.

Ex: `X-/X5-8/9-X811-4/X`
The size of this is 18. So, the legal values to refer are from 0-17 i.e., a[0] to a[17], since indexing in array starts from 0. Towards the end of the program, index counter 'i' becomes 17.

```
if(inputChars[i] == 'X') {               // VALID
        if(inputChars[i+1] == '-') {     // INVALID
            points += 0;
        } else if (inputChars[i+1]== '/') {  // INVALID
            points += 10;
        } else {
            points += Character.getNumericValue(inputChars[i+1]); // INVALID
        }
        if(inputChars[i+2] == '-') { // INVALID
```

You get the general idea here.

Answer (score 0):

At various places in the `public static int getPointsStrikeSpare(int i, char[] inputChars)` method, elements are being accessed which do not belong to the array length boundary. Consider the code blocks:

```
    if(inputChars[i+1] == '-')
```

as well as

```
    if(inputChars[i+2] == '-') {
```

In the case of i == inputChars.length - 1, both `i+1` as well as `i+2` exceed the array length, hence the `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception.